# Oracle 11G Startup failed after altering the number of system processes

Tags: oracle, startup

When I alter the number of system processes to 100000 and restart the database, I get the error below:

```
ORA-27154: post/wait create failed 
ORA-27300: OS system dependent operation:semids_per_proc failed with status: 0
ORA-27301: OS failure message: Error 0
ORA-27302: failure occurred at: sskgpwcr2
ORA-27303: additional information: semids = 524, maxprocs = 100000
```

How can I return it to the normal processes?

Comment: You can't just set the number of processes to any figure you like.  Read this article to understand themore about the pertinent formula. http://h30507.www3.hp.com/t5/Database-Services-NZ/bg-p/662/label-name/semaphores#.UhDFFZKTgnE

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First you can try:

```
STARTUP NOMOUNT
ALTER SYSTEM SET processes=400;
SHUTDOWN IMMEDIATE
STARTUP
```

If Oracle cannot start even in NOMOUNT mode then you can fetch configuration information from spfile:

```
strings $ORACLE_HOME/dbs/spfile$SID.ora > /tmp/pfile
```

Then edit processes in `/tmp/pfile` cleanup some mess made by strings start Oracle with pfile and recreate spfile:

```
STARTUP pfile=/tmp/pfile
CREATE spfile FROM pfile='/tmp/pfile';
```